# Java BigDecimal Possible Overflow Bug

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I was testing boundary conditions on some code involving a `BigDecimal`, and I noticed that when a `BigDecimal` is initialized with the String `"1e2147483647"` it behaves unexpectedly. It seems to have a value between `0` and `1e-2147483647`. When I try calling `intValue()`, I get a `NegativeArraySizeException`. I should note that `2147483647` is the max value of an integer on my system. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a problem with `BigDecimal`?

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("1e2147483647");

test.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0));  //Returns 1
test.compareTo(new BigDecimal("1e-2147483647"));  //Returns -1
test.intValue();  //Throws NegativeArraySizeException
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945985/what-are-the-limits-of-bigdecimal-and-biginteger

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that question. I was just surprised it didn't throw a NumberFormatException from the constructor like it does for a number one digit larger.

Comment: This is more a suggestion than knowing, but `1e-2147483647` is a pretty large number. To be precise, `log_2(10^2147483647) /  8 / 1024^3 = 0.83...` should yield the minimal size (in Gigabytes) to represent such a large number as integer. Maybe this is some kind of memory allocatin problem?

Comment: @DJMatch3000: No, your input is valid and representable, though that's the maximum exponent you can represent for `BigDecimal`.  Your bug is legit.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

No, you appear to have a legit bug. The bug presents in JDK7 but fixed in JDK8. Your values are correctly representable as `BigDecimal`s, and should behave correctly, but don't.

Tracing through [the source code of `BigDecimal`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigDecimal.java.html#2571), on line 2585, `this.precision()` is 1, and `this.scale` is `-2147483647`.  `this.precision() - this.scale` therefore overflows, and the following overflow is not handled correctly.

This bug [has been fixed](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/216a4b93cee8) in JDK8 by [doing the subtraction in `long` arithmetic](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.compareMagnitude%28java.math.BigDecimal%29).

Comment: Does this in Android 17's Java (similar to JDK6)?