# What is longest data type in Android (Java) that I can use to store a value with decimals to use in a calculator app?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a calculator app in Android Studio and want to store the numerical value in a variable.

What is the longest data type in Java which can store the max amount of decimals and what is its limit?

Comment: You can use [`BigDecimal`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal)

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29622364/9110576

Comment: do I just use BigDecimal the same way I would define a float variable?

Comment: Not exactly. You can't use operators such as `+`, but instead call methods such as `add` (which return **new** `BigDecimal` instances, as instances are _immutable_; similar to `String`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need `Big` classes, like [`BigInteger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger) and [`BigDecimal`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal). also inspect other useful for your case classes [extending `Number`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Number):

> AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, DoubleAccumulator, DoubleAdder, Float, Half, Integer, Long, LongAccumulator, LongAdder, Rational, Short

question about max size of these "`Big`s" is answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945985/what-are-the-limits-of-bigdecimal-and-biginteger)